# Why WPF doesn’t raise exceptions to notify about data-binding problems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

```
Try
{
// Data Binding
}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Why .Net Won't Throw any Exception if There is any Error in In Data Binding?
What could be the reason behind this Design?

Comment: Please post an example of an error.  If you try to bind to a readonly property you get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raising exceptions when data binding, WPF provides controls the opportunity to intercept and react to data binding problems.

For example, a numeric up down control bound to a text property could draw a red box around itself, or display a message box in reaction to a bad binding or validation error.

For more info, check out this blog entry: [Displaying Data Validation Messages in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2008/06/27/displaying-data-validation-messages-in-wpf.aspx)

Comment: Downvoted, because I spent time on this and it doesn't look like data validation can be of any help for broken bindings.

Answer (score 0):

The data binding code is deep inside of WPF & it's automatic.  You don't make any calls to update a data binding.  Your code notifies WPF of a change in the value of a bound property though the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and the binding gets updated.

But you can also bind a UI control to a property that doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  In that case, there's no call you can make anywhere in your code to catch an exception.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the other guys have said here, WPF also provides us with the [`PresentationTraceSources` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which we can use to provide us with various levels of feedback relating to data binding (and other areas). You can find out how to utilise the WPF Tracing functionality by viewing the linked page and the [How to: Display WPF Trace Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx) page on MSDN.

Alternatively, error information is also output directly into the Output Window of Visual Studio, so you can still find out what has gone wrong, albeit looking in different places.

The *real* reason why WPF does not throw data binding `Exception`s is probably only known to the development team... I don't suppose that knowing the *actual* reason will help you in any way. Instead, it's better to understand how it works and how to handle errors appropriately.